# Elementor dynamic fields showing all acf fields and acf option page fields

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, elementor, acfpro

Using Elementor Pro and ACF Pro.

So i have setup all acf post/page fields in the acf/init hook. I also setup an options page within the same hook.

In the Elementor editor, when selecting a dynamic field. all ACF fields for posts/pages are listed as an option field. e.g option:banner image. And Nothing is displayed when selecting one.
If i remove the options page. All goes back to normal and can select the actual ACF fields in the dynamic dropdown.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Ive tried adding the options page in functions.php and the options fields in acf/init hook. same result

Answer (score 0):

You should add an image/test to the fields in the page/post edit. Once you add a value to the fields you created in ACF for post/page, they will start to show as in dynamic.